# Can't start Hive and Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I try to install `hive` and `hadoop`. But If I started them though this command `hive --service hiveserver` It errors return like this:

```
/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 258: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 289: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 258: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 289: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Comment: Have you tried: **hadoop version**

Comment: I tested it but the same error:`/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 258: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
/home/babak/Downloads/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Zeile 289: /usr/lib/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
It's german and that means file or folder not found`

Comment: Have you setup HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME ? Whats the OS your on ? Looks like your java path is not right.